# Fusion Table query in App Inventor does not work

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I have the following code blocks in App Inventor:

[image: app inventor]

Note: The red warning is because I have a second btnRemove.Click event which is a disabled block and is not used.

This is my Fusion Table:

[image: Fusion Table]

Right now I am trying to remove the row that has ID number 15 when the button click event is called. If I click the button I see the fusion table window (rotating for a second) and then dissapears. This indicates that something is happening but not what I want it to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because the DELETE statement needs a ROWID to be able to do the delete, see also the [SQL Reference Documentation of the Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#deleteRow).

```
DELETE FROM <table_id>{ WHERE ROWID = <row_id>}
```

which means, for DELETE statements the first step to be done is to get the ROWID of the row to be deleted with a SELECT statement. The second step is to do the DELETE.

Also I would use the `FusiontablesControl.GotResult` event to get the result of the query back, in your case the error message...

Comment: So if I get this right: The complete row shown above has its own id (ROWID) and if I want to delete that row I first need to get that id (GotResult), store the result in a variable (myVar) and then do the delete query where I use the retrieved ROWID ?